# Chrome autofill is overlapping label text mdb css

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, autofill

Im using mdb form inputs.

The problem is that chrome's autocomplete appears to be loading the mobile number and address before this scrip can catch it, giving me strangely overlapping text until I manually focus on it.

mdb input css and js documentation

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/forms/input-fields/

**Issue screenshot**
[image]